# ASPX Files won't load on browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with loading `*.aspx` files on browser.

It actually displays the plain `HTML` instead of loading the proper webpage.

I used IE 11, Google Chrome 33.0 and Mozilla Firefox 27.0.1 and I had the same result.

Does anybody know what's the issue with it? Thanks in advance

Comment: ASPX has to be processed by a server (e.g. IIS). If you load it as a local file - it will load as HTML markup

Comment: Sounds like you are attempting to load the page from the file system, rather than accessing it using http OR the http server you are using does not have the ASP.Net installed OR the directory on your web server is not configured as an ASP.Net application.

Comment: But how could I install IIS on a free webhosting plan? It seems I have to configure the system which is impossible in my case.

Comment: You need to find a hosting plan that supports .NET.